# MySQL - GROUP_CONCAT in WHERE | Less than or Bigger than value

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which does what I want and shows the age of people converted from date of birth. But I now want to narrow my results by saying bigger than or less than those ages but im not sure how to do it.

```
SELECT
  u.`id` as `user_id`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(timestampdiff(year, a.`date_of_birth`, curdate()) separator ',') AS `ages`
FROM
  users u
LEFT JOIN preferences p ON u.`id` = p.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN about a ON u.`id` = a.`user_id`
WHERE
  u.`type` IN ('male','couple')
AND
  p.`couple` = 1
GROUP BY
  u.`id`;
```

So if my results where:

```
|user_id | ages  |  
|--------|-------|
|  1     | 32,31 |  
| 26     | 75    |  
| 30     | 36    |  
| 50     | 35,50 |  
|________|_______|
```

If I were to include into the query age > 30 and age < 40 I would expect to see the following results:

```
|user_id | ages  |  
|--------|-------|
|  1     | 32,31 |  
| 30     | 36    |  
|________|_______|
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: How can happen that one user have two ages? I'm not understanding this part, but after using GROUP BY, limitations can be done within the HAVING clause. For example, `HAVING MAX(timestampdiff(year, a.date_of_birth, curdate())) < SOME_NUMBER`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @D.Smania because its a "couple" so its two people. But I want to ensure both of their ages are within the defined age range. In the case where its a single person "male" then I only need to ensure the single age is within the defined age range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly, you don't need to use `LEFT JOIN` in your case, since you are looking to explicitly filter on the column(s) in both the tables (`about` and `preferences`). A simple `INNER JOIN` would suffice and will be more efficient.
- Now, we will need to find minimum and maximum age value(s) for a grouping on `users.id`. And, then we can use `Having` clause to consider the cases where [minimum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) and [maximum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) age value(s) lie within the required range.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
  u.`id` as `user_id`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, a.`date_of_birth`, CURDATE())) AS `ages`, 
  MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, a.`date_of_birth`, CURDATE())) AS min_age, 
  MAX(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, a.`date_of_birth`, CURDATE())) AS max_age, 
FROM
  users u
JOIN preferences p ON u.`id` = p.`user_id`
JOIN about a ON u.`id` = a.`user_id`
WHERE
  u.`type` IN ('male','couple')
AND
  p.`couple` = 1
GROUP BY
  u.`id` 
HAVING 
  min_age > 30 AND 
  min_age < 40 AND 
  max_age > 30 AND 
  max_age < 40
```